# can't hibernate, access denied

Tags: hibernate, xps

Ubuntu 23.04 on XPS-15-9500

```sh
uri@uri-XPS-15-9500:~$ sudo systemctl hibernate
[sudo] password for uri: 
Call to Hibernate failed: Access denied
```